# QGIS: Return hexagon tiles which intersect with shapefile

Tags: gis, shapefile, qgis

I am trying to compare two shapefiles in QGIS and want to have a result in which only one of the two shapefiles shows the intersecting shapes.

An example what I am trying to achieve can be found here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=03388990d3274160afe240ac54763e57

I have created a hexagon pattern by using the MMQGIS plugin in QGIS with the following result (see picture 1 of the following link):

[Example images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GegVM.jpg)

In the second picture of the Example images link, the shapefile it needs to intersect with and only return hexagons that have an intersect to the shapefile can be seen.

I have tried several vector geoprocessing tools (Intersect, Clip, Difference), but have not been able to get the results I want.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: **Update**: I have found a solution in which I make use of Shapely (Python) and loop through both shapes and return intersecting polygons. The found polygons are written back to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution in which I make use of Shapely (Python) and loop through both shapes and return intersecting polygons. The found polygons are written back to a file.